# Detailed Moderator Election statistics site not updating

Tags: bug, election, election-page

The (brilliantly useful) [site that pulls up extended statistics](http://elections.stackexchange.com/) for candidates running in elections across the SE network does not seem to be updating for current elections. In particular [Christianity](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/) site isn't showing up up at all and [elections are already in primaries](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/election).

Comment: The site has been broken for a while; it was broken for the Stack Overflow elections, for example.

Comment: It was created by a [private user](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/150097/yi-jiang) (i.e. not by Stack Exchange team) looks like he simply did not put all sites. The raw data of the sites is http://elections.stackexchange.com/sites.json and Christianity indeed does not appear there. Yi Jiang appears to be active here on Meta and in the chat, let him know and hopefully he'll fix things up.

Comment: @If all it takes is an update to the json file this shouldn't be a hard fix! Since it's SE hosted, I'm hopeful somebody can poke it into life again.

Comment: Caleb: you could try reporting it [here](http://stackapps.com/questions/2049/stack-exchange-elections-statistics-page)

Comment: @Benjol nice find and great idea, but I fear Mr. Jiang is away for several months already there (last seen in April) and his last real activity was back in Apr 20 '11 at 11:48 so don't think it will do much good.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd He's in chat right now :)

Comment: @balpha yep, meant away from stackapps site.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Update-Update**

The refactored version of the site has been deployed as http://elections.stackexchange.com and should be picking up new elections as they happen. Please write up a new bug report if you run into any further issues.

Tim Stone has access to the VM running this app, so if you notice it behaving badly (or down) a ping to him in chat will probably set the universe right again.

---

There is a replacement for that page written by Tim Stone, which we're testing now for deployment. The reason it's not yet in place is I completely forgot to make sure some node dependency issues were indeed resolved and pass it on (I got it late last week).

Between today and tomorrow I'm going to make sure that everything passes with flying colors, hand it off and (presumably, barring any issues in actual deployment) off it goes.

This is my fault, so feel positively free to blame Shog9 instead.

**Update**

It looks like this is good to go, just a matter of scheduling around some pretty hot projects to get it in place. In the mean time, <strike>I've made it available [here](http://stackelect.noc3270.com) on one of my test servers for anyone that wants to use it, and will keep it there until its put in all proper like.</strike>

Comment: Will it list all sites (taken using the API), or still just a static list that will have to be manually updated?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Even the current version of the site automatically adds new sites based on an RSS feed of election posts on their meta (there's no better way to get a list of sites with current elections at this time), it's just that the process that handles that often ends up stopping for one reason or another. Hopefully we can get this new deployment set up more reliably, though.

Comment: Thanks for getting something up that we can all use. I hacked a copy of the site myself but nobody else could really benefit except from a static dump I made. Would it be fair to link to this dev URL from our official elections page at least until this goes live on the normal URL?

Comment: @Caleb It feels weird to do that, not that I'd personally mind it but it's my own domain, linking to it on something so official just seems a little awkward. What you can do, however, is pin it in the election chat room.

Comment: @TimPost Alright I wasn't sure if that as an SE dev server or your own. I've already posted it in chat.

Comment: Huston, we have a problem. Your test server is returning the host software default envelope, but the final product doesn't seem to have been pushed to the main domain yet. Are we still blaming @Shog9?

Comment: @Caleb Geoff just has to get it deployed, I'll follow up with him this week. I restarted the app, apparently the VM rebooted and I don't have the election app set up from init, thus apache started as normal (emphasis on this being a temporary place to find it)